# What is the proper markup for a Math operator in boldface?

Tags: math-operators

I'd like to render the string `Id` as a Math Operator in upright boldface. What is the proper markup for that? `\mathbf{\operatorname{Id}}`?  `\operatorname{mathbf{Id}}`? `\mathop{\mathbf{Id}}`?

Note; this is for code in a macro, not inline.

Comment: `\operatorname{\mathbf{Id}}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comparison:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\mathbf{\operatorname{Id}}$ is wrong

$\operatorname{\mathbf{Id}}$ seems good

$\mathop{\mathbf{Id}}$ seems good

$\displaystyle\operatorname{\mathbf{Id}}_{X}$ seems good

$\displaystyle\mathop{\mathbf{Id}}_X$ is wrong

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thus the right one is `\operatorname{\mathbf{Id}}`. Of course, if you use it more than a couple of times, you should do

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Id}{\mathbf{Id}}
```

in your document preamble and use `\Id`.

Comment: This is for a macro, not inline. I've edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: Why should `\operatorname{\mathbf{Id}}` be preferred to `\mathop{\mathbf{Id}}`?

Comment: @Patricio Try `\mathop{\mathbf{x}}`

Comment: I just have, but I'm unable to tell the difference.

Comment: Now I see, it's its handling of subindices in displays, isn't it? Sorry for bothering you with this

Comment: @Patricio Not just that: a single character would be moved up or down so it sits symmetrically with respect to the formula axis (where fraction lines are printed).

Comment: Thanks, so much for me to learn!